# How can we algorithmicaly calculate the box with maximum possible volume?

Tags: algorithm

> Johnny needs to make a rectangular box for his physics class project. He has bought P cm of wire and S cm2 of special paper. He would like to use all the wire (for the 12 edges) and paper (for the 6 sides) to make the box.
>
> What is the largest volume of the box that Johnny can make?
>
> Input
>
> The first line contains t, the number of test cases (about 10). Then t test cases follow.
>   Each test case contains two integers P and S in a line (1 ≤ P ≤ 40000, 1 ≤ S ≤ 20000). You may assume that there always exists an optimal solution for the given input cases.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, print a real number that is the largest volume of the box that Johnny can make, rounded to two decimal places.
>
> Example Input:

```
2
20 14
20 16
```

> Output:

```
3.00
4.15
```

> Output details
>
> First case: the dimensions of the largest box may be 3, 1 and 1.
>
> Second case: the dimensions of the largest box may be 7/3, 4/3 and 4/3.

This is a practice problem from www.codechef.com. The name is "[The Best box](http://www.codechef.com/problems/J7)". I don't want the code for this. All I want to know is that how do we solve the problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually trying to solve:

```
maximize V=a*b*c

subject to constraints:

4a+4b+4c = P 
2ab + 2ac + 2bc = S
```

This is a mathematical problem that can be solved using [lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) (Leaving developing the rest to you as an excercise - it is mostly technical, and if done slowly with care, shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: I have tried this method as well. But I guess that applying Lagrange's Multiplier would not be a good idea for solving a problem through computer.

Comment: @KunalSuri It absolutely is -- it's the fastest way to get a solution and the easiest. You could of course try to fiddle with a/b/c iteratively to get a maximum, but that will almost certainly take longer to run, get you an inexact answer, and probably even be harder to code than finding the form of the solution with a little math beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a calculus-free answer.

Considering the constraints:

```
4a+4b+4c = P 
2ab + 2ac + 2bc = S
```

We can rewrite these as:

```
a+b+c = P/4
(a+b+c)^2 - (a^2+b^2+c^2) = S
```

or

```
a+b+c = P/4
a^2+b^2+c^2 = P^2/16 - S
```

In other words: the solutions lie on the intersection of a plane that cuts the main axes at `P/4` and a sphere centered at the origin with radius `P^2/16-S`. This intersection is a circle. Looking at it from above, it looks like an ellipse with its center at 45 degrees from the origin with the short axis along this same line. Moreover:

1. The center is at `(P/12,P/12,P/12)`.
2. The radius is `r = Sqrt(P^2/16-S - 3(P/12)^2)=Sqrt(P^2/24-S)`.
3. The circle lies in a plan e perpendicular to `(1,1,1)`

So, if we have a point on the circle, it will have a displacement relative to the center of `(da,db,dc)`. Because of 3., we know that `dc = -da - db`. Also, the sum of the squares must be equal to the square of the radius, so:

```
r^2 = da^2 + db^2 + (da+db)^2
    = 2(da^2 + db^2 + da db)
```

Now, the displacements are a linear transformation of a circle, so we can parameterize it as follows:

```
dc = -2A cos t
da = A cos t + B sin t
db = A cos t - B sin t
```

Demanding that the length of `(da,db,dc)` is `r`, we get:

```
da^2 + db^2 + dc^2
    =   A^2 cos^2 t +  B^2 sin^2 t + 2AB cos t sin t
      + A^2 cos^2 t +  B^2 sin^2 t - 2AB cos t sin t
     + 4A^2 cos^2 t
    =  6A^2 cos^2 t + 2B^2 sin^2 t
```

For this to be independent of `t`, we must have `6A^2 = 2B^2 = r^2`, so

```
A = r / sqrt(6)
B = r / sqrt(2)
```

and so

```
da = r/sqrt(6) cos t + r/sqrt(2) sin t
db = r/sqrt(6) cos t - r/sqrt(2) sin t
```

and the volume becomes

```
V = (P/12 + da)(P/12 + db)(P/12 - da - db)
  = P^3/1728 + (da db - da(da + db) - db(da + db))P/12 - da db (da + db)
  = P^3/1728 - (da^2 + db^2 + da db)P/12 - da db (da + db)
  = P^3/1728 - P r^2/24 - da db (da + db)
  = C - (r^2/6 cos^2 t - r^2/2 sin^2 t) 2 r/sqrt(6) cos t
  = C - r^3 sqrt(6)/18 (cos^2 t - 3 sin^2 t) cos t
  = C - D (4 cos^2 t - 3 cos^2 t - 3 sin^2 t) cos t
  = C - D (4 cos^3 t - 3 cos t)
  = C - D cos 3t
```

where C and D are positive. Clearly, the maximum is reached when `cos 3t` is `-1`, in which case the volume is:

```
V = P^3/1728 - P(P^2/24-S)/24 + Sqrt(P^2/24-S)^3 Sqrt(6)/18
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  [Lagrange Multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) with multiple constraints. f(x,y,z) = xzy - L1*g(x,y,z) - L2*h(x,y,z) where g(x,y,z)=x + y+ z-P/4 and h(x,y,z)=xy + yz + xz-S/2

Then you do df/dx = 0, df/dy = 0, df/dz = 0, df/dL1 = 0, df/dL2 = 0, you will get 5 equations as follows:

1. yz = L1 + L2*(y+z)
2. xz = L1 + L2*(x+z)
3. xy = L1 + L2*(x+y)
4. x + y + z = p
5. xy + yz + xy = s

Then with a little bit math, you will find out x = y = L2 from 1 2 and 3. Then z = p - 2*L2 from 4 and z = (s - 2*L2^2)/ 2*L2 from 5. Now you can calculate the value of L2 from the above two equations(still remember Quadratic equation?). And the volume is V = xyz = L2 * L2 * (p - 2*L2)

Answer (score -1):

assuming you got the problem at codechef.com/problems/J7

the solution in python 2.7 is

```
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    P = raw_input().split()
    S = int(P[1])
    P = int(P[0])
    V = (P**3)/1728.00 - P*( (P**2)/24.00-S)/24.00 + (((P**2)/24.00-S)**1.5)*(6**0.5)/18
    print("%.2f"%V)
```

Comment: Could please share the logic for V as well?

Comment: This gives the solution but doesn't explain the logic behind it.